# What are the _STARTED_, _COMMITTED_ , and _SUCCESS_ files in a Spark Parquet table?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

What are the *STARTED*, *COMMITTED* , and *SUCCESS* files that are created in the underlying storage folder when writing/creating a Spark Parquet table?
Can there be multiple of those file? If so, what does it mean to have more than one of them?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a commitment protocol, take a read [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/transactional-writes-cloud-storage.html) or watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1_aOPj5ILw)

Answer (score 3):

Those files are stored there by the DBIO transactional protocol.

> With DBIO transactional commit, metadata files starting with `_started_<id>` and `_committed_<id>` accompany data files created by Spark jobs. Generally you shouldn’t alter these files directly. Rather, you should use the VACUUM command to clean them up.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/dbio-commit.html