# Databricks Dataframe is creating multiple files per Write file in a separate directory. Need only 1 file .parquet or .csv

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, parquet

I need some help in the creation of parquet files from dataframes as on write multiple files are created in a seperate directory:
Databricks Python code:

```
mounted_directory_path = "/mnt/myContainer/MyFolder/"
file_list = dbutils.fs.ls(mounted_directory_path)   
    
def insertFirstLineInFile(file_path):
    try:
        header =    ["Model" , "SerialNumber" .....]
        my_df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema","false").option("sep",",").option("header","false").load(file_path)
        my_df = my_df.toDF(*header)
    
    
        # Extract the filename from file_info.path
        filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
        # rename original filename .csv to .parquet
        if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
            # Replace ".csv" with ".parquet"
            filename = filename[:-4] + ".parquet"
        
        OutputFile = OutputDirectory + filename
        print("Filename:", OutputFile)
        # partition to single file
        my_df_single_partition = my_df.coalesce(1)
        my_df_single_partition.write.option("header", "true").parquet(OutputFile)
        
    except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error reading {file_path}: {str(e)}")

for file_info in file_list:
   insertFirstLineInFile(file_info.path)
```

[image]

Is there a cleaner way rather then  having to copy and rename the .parquet, move one level up and delete folder with 4 files.

Many Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you please give me some more details what you are trying here as those files are stored there by the DBIO transactional protocol. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68196969/what-are-the-started-committed-and-success-files-in-a-spark-parquet-tab

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not recommended to change or delete those files created by the DBIO transactional protocol as @funmatters mentioned.

However, you can prevent these from being created by turning off multiple settings as answered here: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/how-do-i-prevent-success-and-committed-files-in-my-write-output/td-p/28690

> 1. We can disable the transaction logs of spark parquet write using `spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass=org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol`. This will help to disable the "committed" and "started" files but still _SUCCESS, _common_metadata and _metadata files will generate.
> 2. We can disable the _common_metadata and _metadata files using `parquet.enable.summary-metadata=false`
> 3. We can also disable the _SUCCESS file using `mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs=false`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your dataframe to pandas and write it to `.csv` or `.parquet`. It doesn't create any of those files shown in your image.

Below is the data.

[image]

Write the data as below.

```
df.toPandas().to_parquet("/dbfs/user.parquet")
```

After writing you will get a file, which is given in the path.

[image]

Again reading the file and converting into spark dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_parquet("/dbfs/user.parquet"))
df.show()
```

[image]

Or

As @Zach King given you disable those parquet configuration and write the file.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass","org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol")
spark.conf.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata","false")
spark.conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs","false")
df.coalesce(1).write.parquet("/singlefile/")
```

output:

You will get single file output.

[image]

Comment: HI, Tks for your comment. Apparently Pandas cannot handle large files and was aborting above 65535bytes. That's why I have used Spark in the first place.